# Regex to test files names for webpack loader and exlucde *.test.js. Include file-name.js but not

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I want to include the following: filename.js, file-name.js, file-name-test.js

But exclude: filename.test.js, file-name.test.js, file-name-test.js

Comment: Good to know but where is the problem?

Comment: I need a regex to match according these filenames

Comment: check your string, not end with `test.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included `file-name-test.js` both in what you wanted to include **and** exclude. Assuming you wanted to **include** it, the code below should help you on your way.

```
var pat = /^[\w-]+.[\w-]+$/;

"filename.js".match(pat);
// ["filename.js"]

"file-name.js".match(pat);
// ["file-name.js"]

"file-name-test.js".match(pat);
// ["file-name-test.js"]

//-----

"filename.test.js".match(pat);
// null

"file-name.test.js".match(pat);
// null
```